# Modeling Pre-Trends in Difference-in-Differences

Tags: r, econometrics, interaction, difference-in-difference, test-for-trend

To get right to the point, the canonical difference-in-differences design is as follows:

$$
y_{it} = \alpha + \gamma T_{i} + \lambda Post_{t} + \delta (T_{i} \times Post_{t}) + \varepsilon_{it},
$$

where $T_{i}$ is group-level indicator equal to 1 for all entities $i$ in the treatment group. $Post$ is a dummy indexing the period when the policy is in effect, irrespective of group. I have witnessed the following specification in other scholarly work:

$$
y_{it} = \alpha + \gamma T_{i} + \xi Pre_{t} +  \lambda Post_{t} + \rho  (T_{i} \times Pre_{t}) + \delta (T_{i} \times Post_{t}) + \varepsilon_{it},
$$

where $Pre_{t}$ often denotes the pre-period time trend. Suppose I am observing crimes in districts $i$ over months $t$. Let $t$ be a monthly interval such that $t = 1,2,3, …, 12$. And, let the policy begin on June 1st and end on September 30th (Post = 1 for June, July, August, and September). My question concerns how to structure the *pre*-period time trend variable $Pre_{t}$. **To be specific, does it mean letting $Pre_{t}$ enter the model as a simple integer from 1 to 5, but take on a value of zero for all values on or after June? Or, would a series of pre-period month dummies do a better job of accounting for pre-existing differences in group trends?** Obviously, I would have to omit another month (i.e., January) to avoid collinearity with $Post_{t}$.

If I create a 'month' variable with integer values from 1 to 12, then the variable would be a full continuous trend variable, and not a *pre*-period time trend. In sum, I want to account for potential trend differences between groups *pre*-exposure to the policy. I could provided references to articles where I have seen this structure recommended.

I am grateful for any and all responses (or comments).

Comment: I wonder if you are misinterpreting the second specification. I think the typical practice is to have period dummies and period dummied interacted with T rather than linear time terms and their interactions with treatment. So this would give you a sequence of $\rho$s and $\delta$s (assuming you have multiple pre and post periods). This is why Post and Post have $t$ subscripts. The test of parallel trends is that all the $\rho$s are jointly zero, which you hope will persist in the post period.

Comment: See equation (36) [here](https://www.nber.org/papers/w14251).

Comment: I am probably misinterpreting it. The NBER paper was helpful. Here is the article where I saw this specification (Pg. 326, Model 3). Sorry for not providing a link to an un-gated copy: <https://www.mathematica-mpr.com/our-publications-and-findings/publications/differenceindifferences-methods-in-public-finance>.